# ECHO of an object breaking page

Tags: php

I have the following code that when used breaks my page. What am I not doing correctly?

```
$check_availability = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytablename "));

foreach ($check_availability as $available){
    echo  $available . "<br>\n";
}
```

Ive tried moving the echo out of the loop. Same broken page result. This worked correctly when I had NO foreach loop at all but then it would only return 1 result instead of many.

**EDIT 1** to show var_dump($available) result inside the loop -

```
object(stdClass)#2314 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" } object(stdClass)#2361 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" }
```

If I var_dump($check_availability ) outside of the loop then I get

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2314 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2361 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" } } array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2314 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2361 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" } }
```

Comment: Based on reading this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/ it looks like `get_results` returns an array of objects. So if `$available` is an object, you can't echo it. You probably need to use `echo $available->id`. (I don't really do wordpress, so it's just my best guess.)

Comment: for debugging, and proving or disproving Don’t Panic’s idea, you could do a `print_r($available)` or `var_dump($available)`

Comment: Thanks but why would it work outside of the loop?

Comment: @Timmorton when vardump() outside the loop I get an object(stdClass). But only one of the results as expected. When I use it in the loop  it shows me multiple standard objects as it should.

Comment: Please edit post to show results. I don’t work with wordpress either, so I have no idea what the method should return.

Comment: @timmorton added. I could be wrong, but doesnt seem like a WP issue since the only difference in WP in this instance is the MYSQL global $wpdb and the bad error reporting. Everything else works like normal usually.

Comment: could you use code block (3 back tics) and show the indentation on the var dump?  That’ll make it much easier to figure out. thanks

Comment: but regardless, as was mentioned before, you need to specify which property you want to print, because printing an object is an error (unless the object has the `__toString()` method)

Comment: @timmorton sorry I am not familiar with the 3 back ticks? How would that look?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words... I edited your post to put the code blocks in, but left it for you to add indentation (I’m on a phone; edits are not fun..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "echo" function can only print strings / numbers.
In this case you are trying to print an object.

If you want to print the id try writing:

```
   $check_availability = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytablename "));

foreach ($check_availability as $available){
    echo $available->id . "<br>\n";
}
```

If you are interested in knowing what '$available' contains, run this:

```
   $check_availability = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytablename "));

foreach ($check_availability as $available){
    var_dump($available);
}
```